# NGINX + phpFPM load balancer and sessions

Tags: php, session, nginx

i have one question, i am using **nginx** and **PHPFPM**.
I am using loadbalancer for **2 phpfpm servers**.

To keep sessions from both phpfpm servers synced i used memcached.
But when i use memcached i see that **page is slowing down**.

When i use **files as sessions save type** web is runing faster, but sessions are not synced imediately (i guess files are owerwriting). I am using NFS to share sessions.

Any ideas please how to sync sessions when using nginx loadbalancer for phpfpm servers?

Comment: What does i mean: 'page is slowing down'? It's a visual effect or you performed some measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed increase you're probably seeing here in PHP using NFS over memcached is a *deceptive* one by nature. PHP session storage defaults to lock acquisition on a first-come-first-served basis. Which means that two concurrent requests made to PHP for the same session will cause the first request to lock the session until either PHP is done or you explicitly call [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/session-write-close) from your code, to release the lock.

But in a file based session store, PHP relies on flock, which doesn't work in NFS.

> The NFS (Versions 2 and 3) protocol **does not** support file locking
>
> [See this answer on unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229680)

So for a distributed session store, you rarely want slow file-system based lock. Most in-memory stores work faster anyway. And since NFS can't typically handle flock calls, your sessions ***will get corrupted*** if two concurrent requests try to write to the same session file. In other words, what you're seeing as *faster* is just basically your requests potentially corrupting their sessions *faster*, because there's no lock on the session for concurrency.

If your requests take a really long time and don't require the session it's best to explicitly call `session_write_close` as early in the code as possible when you are done with the session so that any other concurrent requests coming in can get at the session. This is typically a problem when you're doing a lot of long-polling requests to PHP (say over AJAX).